# Ghost4J can't find gs_init.ps

Tags: ghost4j

I want to compress a scanned PDF useing ghost4j. While doing that I get following Error 
First, I am doing some tests if the Files and Directories are available, then starting Initializing Ghost4J:

Output:

> ```
> input.pdf is available
> ```
>
> C:/gs/gs9.15/lib is available
>   C:/gs/gs9.15/bin is available
>   DIRS: -I"C:/gs/gs9.15/lib;C:/gs/gs9.15/bin"
>   2014-10-07 14:47:11  [ERROR] (Ghostscript):72 - GPL Ghostscript 8.61: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.
>   ERROR: Cannot initialize Ghostscript interpreter. Error code is -100
>   org.ghost4j.GhostscriptException: Cannot initialize Ghostscript interpreter. Error code is -100
>       at org.ghost4j.Ghostscript.initialize(Ghostscript.java:365)

```
at kompressPDF.KompressPDF.main(KompressPDF.java:61)
```

Code:

> ```
>   File inputFile = new File("input.pdf");
> ```

```
    Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();
    gs.getRevision();

    String[] gsArgs = new String[7];
    gsArgs[0] = "dirs";
    gsArgs[1] = "-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen";
    gsArgs[2] = "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite";
    gsArgs[3] = "-dNOPAUSE";
    gsArgs[4] = "-dBATCH";  
    gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=output.pdf";  
    gsArgs[6] = inputFile.getAbsolutePath();    

    try {
        gs.initialize(gsArgs);
        gs.exit();
    } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Where Variable "dirs" = -I"C:/gs/gs9.15/lib;C:/gs/gs9.15/bin"
Does anybody know, how I can solve the problem?

Thanks
GGK